# SPSS syntax: Assigning a value to a data file based on a macro variable

Tags: syntax, spss

I already have my macro variable created, now I need to insert this variable into a data set.
I made the following attempt, but something went wrong.

```
GET FILE=!QUOTE(!CONCAT("C:\SPSS_Temp\Output_Regression_",!atribute2digits,".SAV")).

STRING Depend (A64).
COMPUTE Depend = "HERE".
EXECUTE.

DO IF $CASENUM=1.
WRITE OUTFILE="C:\SPSS_Temp\PrintDepend.SPS" /
"DEFINE !PrintDepend()"
" IF ( Depend = 'HERE') Depend = !QUOTE( "
!QUOTE(!EVAL(!DEPENDENT))
")."
" !ENDDEFINE."
.
END IF.
EXECUTE.

INCLUDE "C:\SPSS_Temp\PrintDepend.SPS".

!PrintDepend.
EXECUTE.

SAVE OUTFILE=!QUOTE(!CONCAT("C:\SPSS_Temp\Output_FINAL_Regression_",!atribute2digits,".SAV")).
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It would be great if you narrowed down your question to where exactly you get the error, what the error message is, and any other further details you may have. Simply posting "my syntax is not working, debug it!" is not the best way to get help.

Comment: You'll have to help us to help you... Please edit your post and add the actual error message.